# SwitchMap with delayed observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

```
 Observable
     .interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .switchMap(integer -> 
        Observable
                 .just(integer * 2) 
                 .delay(5,SECONDS))
     .subscribe(integer -> { System.out.println(integer);});
```

As I understood, after switch map we should subscribe to last created observable, so I expect output "8" after 20 seconds, but it waits forever

Comment: `interval()` is a static factory method that creates a new sequence, ignoring `range` before it ([see this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/a-static-method-should-be-accessed-in-a-static-way/)). Your IDE should be warning you about invoking a static method on an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation of `switchMap()` operator goes as follows:

1. Receive a value emitted from upstream
2. Invoke the function argument with the emitted value, which must be an observable
3. Subscribe to the observable
4. Emit any items from that observable
5. When a new item is emitted from upstream, unsubscribe from the observable in step 3, and start at step 2.

The result is that the delayed observable will never emit anything because it will be unsubscribed every 2 seconds.

You will need to use `flatMap()` operator instead, which will not unsubscribe on each emitted value.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's the best explanation of switchMap. But how it will behave if it is not infinite interval, fixed amount of emmisions or user input? I tried such way, however it worked same

Comment: I tried filter after interval and it works fine!
But with interval range, not working for some reason

Comment: If the up-stream observable terminates, then the final item would be emitted. Essentially, the up-stream observable overrides the subscription, starting from the beginning. Using `flatMap()` will cause each constructed observable to run to completion.